# How To Create a Drop Down with Macros

Tags: excel, vba, macos, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I am trying to create a drop down list that will run a macro with each option selection. The drop down list will contain "Google" and New Businesses". When Google is selected, I need a certain macro to run. I have the macros codes ready to go, just wondering if this is even possible since I am working on a Macbook.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F4")) Is Nothing Then
Select Case Range("F4")
    Case "Google": Google
    Case "New Businesses": New_Businesses
End Select
End If
End Sub
```

The code above is located in the first sheet with Worksheet and Change as the drop down options. The following codes are located in Module1:

```
Sub Google()
'First Macro
Call GoogleManagementFee
'Second Macro
Call HideTermsAndConditions
End Sub

Sub GoogleManagementFee()
Sheets("THIRD-PARTY").Range("C26").Value = 0
End Sub

Sub HideTermsAndConditions()
Worksheet("SOW").Range("54:110").Rows.Hidden = True
End Sub

Sub New_Businesses()
Call UnhideTermsAndConditions
Call ManagementFee10
End Sub

Sub UnhideTermsAndConditions()
Range("54:110").Rows.Hidden = False
End Sub

Sub ManagementFee10()
Sheets("THIRD-PARTY").Range("C26").Value = 0.10
End Sub
```

I believe these codes should enable macros to run when I select either Google or New Businesses from the drop down menu I created. I'm wondering if I need to download ActiveX or if I simply did something wrong with the codes.

Comment: Since you have not posted any attempt all I will say is you need to use the `Worksheet_Change` event handler.

Comment: Sorry about that, let me add in my attempted code.

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Sheets("SOW").Range("F4") = "Google" Then
        Call Google
    End If
    If Sheets("SOW").Range("F4") = "New Businesses" Then
       Call New_Businesses
    End If
    If Sheets("SOW").Range("F4") = "Stepan" Then
        Call Stepan
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub